# How to add tooltip on a disabled button in a button group (Angular)?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

If I would need to add a tooltip to a disabled button, I would just wrap the button and place the tooltip on the wrapper.
But how can I add a tooltip to a disabled button if the button is part of a button group? I of course could again use a wrapper, but the button group wouldn't look correct anymore. I would like to not add any extra css for this.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="...">
        ...
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="...">
        ...
    </button>
    // this is bad as it breaks the button group style
    <div [ngbTooltip]="someConditionThatCanBeTrue ? 'tooltipMessage' : ''">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button"
                [disabled]="someConditionThatCanBeTrue" (click)="...">
            ...
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<button disabled="true" title="title">hello</button>` isnt this worked out for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply adding `btn-group btn-group-sm` class to the:

```
<div **class="btn-group btn-group-sm"** [ngbTooltip]="someConditionThatCanBeTrue ? 'tooltipMessage' : ''">
  .....
</div>
```